# How to automaticly open a URL at specific times each day

Tags: cron

I am using kubuntu 14.04. I have installed cron using sudo apt-get install cron, and then I created this file in IDLE, called `openurl.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://eample.com')
```

I then typed `chmod +x openurl.py` into the terminal to make the .py file excecutionable. If I type in`./openurl.py` to the terminal, the script works.

then, using the kickoff application launcher I clicked system settings > task scheduler > new task > then I searched for the openurl.py file, and selected when I wanted it to run.

If I type `crontab -e` into the terminal, this is displayed:

```
#openurl
21 21 * * *     /home/craig/openurl.py


# File generated by KCron the Thursday 29 Jan 2015 21:20.
```

And then I wait, and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How often do you want this crontab to run?

Comment: Every day, at the same time

Comment: K. Just checking, cause unless I'm doing the math wrong this will be every day @ 9:21pm

Comment: That is correct :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727991).
Change the `cron`'s crontab to launch your preferred `Python` interpreter with the script path as argument:

```
21 21 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/craig/openurl.py
```

Remember that a standard symbolic link will point to the default version of the interpreter, which may not be correct if your software is based on the 2.X syntax of `Python`.
The `cron` daemon *may* launch the interpreter with elevated rights, **use a restricted interpreter for automated security-critical tasks**.

**EDIT** to cover a bigger slice of problems after the cronjob setup:
To **monitor in real-time the jobs** done by `cron` and other system daemons, execute in a terminal:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

or

```
tailf /var/log/syslog
```

(on some systems the path of the log file is different, like `/var/log/cron.log`)
To **redirect the OUTPUT of a cron job**, insert a shell redirection for STDOUT in the cronjob file, like:

```
21 21 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/craig/openurl.py >> /home/craig/test.log
```

In a `Python` script a command like `print('TEST')` will append the string *TEST* to `test.log`; any simple subprocess will be also redirected.
Simply check the file to know if the script works as expected.
Please, feel free to comment under here if you have more questions and don't forget to press the left UP arrow and mark as Favorite if I'm of any help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Or better yet, click the check to mark as accepted.

Comment: An explicit call to the interpreter is suggested, because the interpretation of the Magic Number in a script may be different for each shell: an update of the default shell can cause an unpredictable behaviour. The best thing to do is call the interpreter with a verbose/extended syntax and absolute paths. This is a valid suggestion for every *nix system and will help in every administrative task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is all very helpful. I have a few follow up questions though if that is okay? I only started using Linux today so I am a complete beginner. What is the `cron`'s crontab?

Comment: @LorenzoAncora I changed the cron script to `57 22 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/craig/openurl.py` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Blue7 a crontab is a configuration file used by cron and affine daemons to execute system and user tasks, it requires an automated procedure to be installed, modified ecc. and should have correct permissions on the file-system. The crontab utility does all for you, except the configuration, for which you MUST read the manual (Unix way...).

Comment: @Blue7 To diagnose your problem, execute 'tail /var/log/cron.log' immediately after the time programmed for the script execution. If the log file says that there are wrong privileges set for the crontab, you should correct the problem immediately by changing the global crontab owner and group. If the log says CMD (YOURCOMMAND), then the command was executed but produced no OUTPUT and you should fix your script. To diagnose the problem with a log, execute a redirection in the programmed execution line, as follows: 21 21 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/craig/openurl.py > /home/craig/openurl.log

Comment: I get the error `tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/cron.log’ for reading: No such file or directory`.
I've had a quick read of [this manual](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html) and from tis and something someone else mentioned, I think its a problem with the environment. `openurl.py` works when run directly from the terminal, but not from cron, because cron doesn't know how to use the GUI i'm using and the web browswer i'm using. What can I add to the `openurl.py` script to make this work? Or is the .py script fine, and its the crontab I need to change?

Comment: @Blue7 a default Ubuntu installation uses the syslog for cron, I've made a mistake because my Lubuntu installation uses a separate log for maintenance reasons. In your case, executing 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron' should give the desired result. I've decided to try your script in my installation for a fast diagnose and it gets invoked: you should debug the 'webbrowser' module because it fails to launch the browser. Try something like that with OUTPUT redirection to know if the process calling works well with cron: http://pastebin.com/HaBZeZAU  - just an example.

Comment: Check Below AtilioA's Answer too , for me it worked after that modification  ( modification in cron job with `DISPLAY=:0` parameter )

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as you. Your job might be failing because it requires an [X session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), since you're trying to open a web browser. You should put `export DISPLAY=:0;` after the schedule in your cronjob, as in

```
21 21 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/python /home/craig/openurl.py >> /home/craig/test.log

 python3 /home/fin/Labs/my-cheatcodes/src/dsktp_startup_script/dsktp_startup_script.py > capture_report.txt
```

If this doesn't work, you could try replacing `:0` with the output of `echo $DISPLAY` in a graphical terminal.